# Click event not propagating to child view

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

I have an activity A1 which has several views

and another class ViewGenerator which has a method that returns a view via method getView()

I call this method by creating an object for A1 and calling getView. 
my class is working fine and I am able to get the view. however any child of that view is not clickable, click event is not fired on that child.

here is A1's getView method

```
public View getView(Main ctx) {

    return getArticleView();

}
```

here is getArticleView

```
private View getArticleView(Main ctx) {
    LayoutInflater lft = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout lin = (RelativeLayout) lft.inflate(
            R.layout.article_view, null);
    RelativeLayout articleView = (RelativeLayout) lin
            .findViewById(R.id.article_view);

    summaryStuff(ctx);

    return articleView;
}
```

here is summaryStuff

```
private void sharingStuff(final Main ctx) {
    LayoutInflater lft = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout lin = (RelativeLayout) lft.inflate(R.layout.summary_bar,
            null);
    bookmarkRibbon = (ImageView) lin.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_selector);
    bookmarkRibbon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bookmarkRibbon.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark_yellow);
        }
    });
}
```

as you can see bookmarkRibbon has a listener. however it is not clickable or at least the event is not fired

get View is called from Activity's onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

ImageView, by default are not clickable, i:e cannot register click events.

make sure you set The imageview clickable

```
bookmarkRibbon.setClickable(true);
```

right after referencing it.

Comment: that doesn't seem to make any difference, and I suppose ImageView are clickable because I use them as such all the time.